# How to take a negative ranged prior using pymc package?

Tags: bayesian, pymc

I was trying to fit bayesian linear regression using pymc package. But for certain model coefficients I need to choose the prior as a negative ranged distribution (for example negative halfnormal) so that I get always negative estimates for those coefficients and the hdi range should also lie in the negative range.

```py
with pm.Model() as model:

    mu = pm.HalfNormal('mu',1)
    mean = pm.Deterministic('mean', -mu)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', 1)
    likelihood = pm.Normal('likelihood', mu=mean, sigma=sigma, observed=data)
    trace = pm.sample(2000, tune=1000)
    
print(pm.summary(trace))
```

I tried the above code but it is only converting the positive signs of mean into negative signs rather than sampling randomly from a negative ranged distribution. How can I modify my code.

Comment: Why "sampling positive values and transforming them to negative" would anyhow differ from "sampling negative values"? It seems to be doing exactly what you need. If $x$ is a positive number and you need it to be negative, $-x$ is negative.